# Single event listener for multiple child elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Consider the following HTML code:

```html
<section>
    <div id="left-box"></div>
    <div id="middle-box"></div>
    <div id="right-box"></div>
</section>
```

I want to change the color of `<section>` every time one of the above boxes is clicked. I am not presenting the CSSs. Is it possible instead of using 3 event listeners for click events upon the 3 boxes just to use only one? I've heard about **fragments**. Any idea?

Comment: Bind the event-listener to the `section` to listen for the clicks/events.

Comment: And how then is it possible to tell which of the three boxes is clicked?

Comment: Just check event object that pass to the handler.

Comment: Are the ids necessary in this case?

Comment: @ILIAS: an `id` is rarely, if *ever*, necessary; for JavaScript they're just an easy means to select, or specify, certain nodes for certain purposes. It's often 'better' to use an `id`, otherwise you may have to first identify the DOM to work out which element to use and select, and then your JavaScript is dependant on your DOM and its structure. So, it's *easier*, but never strictly *necessary* to use an `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single listener on the `<section>` which contains the three `<div>` elements, and then check for `event.target` to see if one of those is clicked. So your code will only run if you click one of the three boxes, and not the parent `<section>` element.

Here's an example. I added an ID, class and some CSSs just for clarity.

```js
var section = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == "box") {
    // You clicked on a box
    container.style.backgroundColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
  }
});

document.getElementById("left-box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById("middle-box").style.backgroundColor = "green";
document.getElementById("right-box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container>div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <div class="box" id="left-box"></div>
  <div class="box" id="middle-box"></div>
  <div class="box" id="right-box"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you attach the event listener to the `section`, then you can find the element that was clicked on.

```
var section = document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0];
section.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.toElement);
});
```